# How do you beat a person with control over physics?

Tags: physics, science-fiction

So let's assume somebody has control over all physics.  This person, let's call him David, is effected by his own physics.  I'm currently writing a book based on the Half-Life series, and with the focus on physics, there is a person in my book with control over them.  How would you possibly defeat this person?
David effected by his own physics
David has control over all physics
How do you beat him?  Trying to fire a gun at him?  He just increases the air friction to stop it.

Edit:  Yes, this is theoretical.  He has control over these 'fundamental laws of the universe', and he can simply "increase the air friction".  If he changes the laws of physics in one instance, then he changes it everywhere, for example, he can't just suspend an object in air because "this area has no gravity", everywhere has no gravity now.

Edit:  For my purposes, any changes to physics don't violently explode the earth for example; Removing gravity doesn't explode everything.  My book has three characters, which have control over people's vision, control over physics, and control over time.  This character can control physics, and with the snap of a finger, Poof, there is no gravity.  They are confined to a classroom, with guns, tables, chairs, pencils, everything you'd find in a classroom, but nothing else is there.  How do you defeat this person who has control over physics?

Comment: Related discussion on Meta: [What to do about unstoppable questions?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions)

Comment: 1) make him use his power
2) watch reality reaping itself appart
3) profit

Comment: Hi, Nate Dukes. Your question is not very well constrained, and there's currently no easy way to rank one answer over another, or determine if an answer is fully correct. Please edit your question to explain the specific details of what your superpower can and cannot do, and what makes one answer better than another - that is, what objective criteria it should satisfy.

Comment: Wait wait wait... this you will have to clarify: what do you mean "has control over physics"? The big issue here is that all concepts you have of "physics" are **models**. There is no such thing as "friction" in real life. "Friction" is just a convenient model that we humans use to make sense of how an object moving through a medium such as air behaves.  But the **actual** physical laws, when originating from the four fundamental forces of the universe, along with the strange nature of space-time, of matter and particles, are next to incomprehensible when to moving from the micro to the macro.

Comment: So you will have to clarify this a bit because "has control over physics" is much too vague and undefined. Add constraints. Explain the abilities and lay out the rules for them. Otherwise this question is much too unclear and way too broad to be answerable.

Comment: One does not simply `increase the air friction`. How does he do that exactly? "Air friction" is a mathematical model to express the resistance a moving body faces, when travelling through air, as a number. It doesn't have any real meaning.

Comment: @Sefa: You mean, 3)  run away from the point where reality is collapsing, right?

Comment: Super powers are better left unexplained :) just like @nzaman said, air friction is just a model that allows us to calculate good enough approximation of what really happened. Relativistic quantum physics is much more detailed model. And down there we find only few laws and constants that seem fundamental and not just a model and a way of calculation. But you can't change them workout making universe shut down.

Comment: If there is no gravity _**anywhere**_, the universe explodes into a cloud of atomic dust, everything dies. The End.

Comment: As interesting as a superpower might be, you can still sneak up behind a guy like this and shoot him or whatever. His brain sounds very normal.

Comment: Duh, just stab him when he's asleep.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/52243/10851

Answer (score 3):

### Fire a bullet at him

David has control over the laws of physics so he will increase air resistance sufficiently to stop a bullet meaning the very carefully evolved aveoli in his lungs can no longer do their jobs properly and he suffocates (along with all sorts of other problems).

Unfortunately this does kill everyone else too.

We are evolved to a very specific sets of physics, fusion inside stars is precariously balanced - if some constants had been ever so slightly different it may never have happened. The list goes on.

Essentially, if he ever uses his powers he could risk wiping out all life with just the slight tweak of a constant let alone adapting it so drastically as to stop a bullet with air.

Comment: Say these people are isolated in a separate plane of reality.  Doesn't kill thousands of people.  Is it possible for them to survive if they do this, say you hold your breath?

Comment: @NateDukes The problem for aveoli is in the transfer of air through membranes - this is a problem with processing the air already inside your lungs. It would be more like drowning that suffocation - filling up your lungs with something that you cannot process. It may be that you could survive some small period of time but then all we require are more bullets. The real problem is the knock on effects of however you decide to change the physics. The body probably depends on a certain resistivity  of air for many different things.

Comment: He can just make lead intensely radioactive for an instant and vaporize the bullet (but not for long enough to cause a full-fledged nuclear explosion), and greatly increase the opacity of air to whatever type of radiation the bullet emitted so that he doesn't die of radiation poisoning the next instant. Of course, everything that's made of lead in the universe is toast.